# Fast and low-memory-consumption way to read in pair of numbers from file and process them?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Okay, so this is my challenge taken from CodeEval. I have to read numbers from a file that is formatted in a standard way, it has a pair of numbers separated by a comma on each line (x, n). I have to read in the pair values and process them, then print out the smallest multiple of n which is greater than or equal to x, where n is a power of 2.

EXACT REQUIREMENT: **Given numbers x and n, where n is a power of 2, print out the smallest multiple of n which is greater than or equal to x. Do not use division or modulo operator.**

I have come up with a number of solutions, but none of them satisfy the computer's conditions to let me pass the challenge. I only get a partial completion with scores that vary from 30 to 80 (from 100).

I'm assuming that my solutions do not pass the speed but more likely the memory-usage requirements.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can enlighten me and offer some better, more efficient solutions.

Here are two of my solutions:

```
        var filePath = @"C:\Users\myfile.txt";

        int x;
        int n;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string numsFile = string.Empty;
            while ((numsFile = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var nums = numsFile.Split(',').ToArray();
                x = int.Parse(nums[0]);
                n = int.Parse(nums[1]);

                Console.WriteLine(DangleNumbers(x, n));
            }
        }
```

<<<>>>

```
        var fileNums = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        foreach (var line in fileNums)
        {
            var nums = line.Split(',').ToArray();

            x = int.Parse(nums[0]);
            n = int.Parse(nums[1]);

            Console.WriteLine(DangleNumbers(x, n));
        }
```

**Method to check numbers**

```
    public static int DangleNumbers(int x, int n)
    {
        int m = 2;
        while ((n * m) < x)
        {
            m += 2;
        }

        return m * n;
    }
```

I'm fairly new to C# and programming but these two ways I found to get the best score from several others I have tried. I'm thinking that it's not too optimal for a new `string` to be created on each iteration, nor do I know how to use a `StringBuilder` and get the values into an `Int` from it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated as I would really like to get this challenge passed.

Comment: why are you doing m+=2? If x is 14 and n is 5 wouldn't you want to print out 15 rather than the 20 that this function gives? Could your score be bad just because your program is wrong?

Comment: 1. Take care to create as much variables as possible outside of the loop. Why creating them on each round, when you can simply re-set their value?
2. Same goes for the `DangleNumbers` function. There's no need to create that same `m` each time, just make it a global readonly integer, since you need its constant value.
+That you'd need to just `m++`, so that you can check all the consequent multipliers and not skip by 2 each time.

Comment: Why would you increment `m` by 2 and start with `m = 2`?

Comment: Regarding the memory usage. The second solution is not good because it loads the whole file in memory. The first solution is ok, except the `ToArray` call which is unnecessary, so you can safely remove it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not list all the constraints. Given numbers x and n, where n is a power of 2.  So n has to be a power of 2, and it will increase each time the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: I don't think the score can be bad if the program is wrong, because I get the desired output, they just don't give it a 100 score. If the output is not as the one they are expecting, the program would just fail. And as far as my searches have shown me, it has to be a matter of memory usage. Because I got speeds as low as 27ms. And compared to other tasks completed, 27 is on the low/fast side.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused the maths is the same even if n is a power of 2... Consider if n is 8 (a power of 2) and x is 20 then the lowest multiple of n greater than 20 is 24 (ie m = 3)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The smallest multiple of `n` that is larger or equal to `x` is likely this:</s>

```
if(x <= n)
{
    return n;
}
else
{
    return x % n == 0 ? x : (x/n + 1) * n;
}
```

As x and n are integers, the result of x/n will be truncated (or effectively rounded down). So the next integer larger than x that is a multiple of n is (x/n + 1) * n

Since you missed the requirements, the modulo version was the most obvious choice. Though you still got your method wrong. m = 2 would not result in the smallest being returned but it could actually be the double of the smallest if n is already larger than x.

x = 7, n = 8 would get you 16 instead of 8.

Also adding 2 to m would result in a similar problem.

x = 5, n = 2 would get you 8 instead of 6.

use the following method instead:

```
public static int DangleNumbers(int x, int n)
{
    int result = n;
    while(result < x)
        result += n;
    return result;
}
```

Still capable of begin optimized but at least right according to the (now) stated constraints.

Comment: I have updated the requirements. I did not offer the complete list of constraints. I am not allowed to use modulo or division operator.

Comment: You sir, deserve a beer! Thank you! I guess I never tested that method well enough and I just focused all my attention on the IO and string operations after I got a few good samples and passed their output test using my method.

Comment: This still doesn't handle an int overflow though, so you have to be careful if that list contains large integer values.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to improve the solution with some suggestions from you guys and take the variables outside the loop and drop the `ToArray()` call which was redundant.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var filePath = @"C:\Users\sorin\Desktop\sorvas.txt";

        int x;
        int n;
        string[] nums;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string numsFile = string.Empty;
            while ((numsFile = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                nums = numsFile.Split(',');
                x = int.Parse(nums[0]);
                n = int.Parse(nums[1]);

                Console.WriteLine(DangleNumbers(x, n));
            }
        }

    }


    public static int DangleNumbers(int x, int n)
    {
        int m = 2;
        while ((n * m) < x)
        {
            m += 2;
        }

        return m * n;
    }
```

So it looks like this. The thing is that even if now the numbers have slightly improved, I got a lower score.

[image]

May it be their system to blame ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the first option of reading line by line (rather than reading all lines) is clearly going to use less memory (except potentially in the case where the file is very small (eg "1,1") in which case the overhead of the reader may cause problems but at that point the memory used is probably irrelevant.

Likewise declaring the variables outside the loop is generally better but in this case since the objects are value types I'm not sure it makes a difference.

Lastly the most efficient way of doing your DangleNumbers method is probably using bitwise logic operators and the fact that n is always a power of 2. Here is my attempt:

```
public static int DangleNumbers3(int x, int n)
{
    return ((x-1) & ~(n-1))+n;
}
```

Essentially it relies on the fact that in binary a power of n is always a 1 followed by zero or more zeros. Thus a multiple of n will always end in that same number of zeros. So if n has M zeros after the one then you can take the binary form of x and if it already ends in M zeros then you have your answer. Otherwise you zero out the last M digits at which point you have the multiple of n that is just under x and then you add 1.

In the code `~(n-1)` is a bitmask that has M zeros at the end and the leading digits are all 1. Thus when you AND it with a number it will zero out the trailing digits. I apply this to `(x-1)` to avoid having to do the check for if it is already the answer and have special cases.

It is important to note that this only works because of the special form of n as a power of 2. This method avoids the need for any loops and thus should run much faster (it has five operations total and no branching at all compared to other looping methods which will tend to have at the very least an operation and a comparison per loop.